# wordpress how to remove ? from the url using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, plugins, url-rewriting, query-string

i having a URL http://www.domain.com/wp/application/?productname

I want  to change it to http://www.domain.com/wp/application/productname . 
if i have treated like this then page not found error is display.
i don't have use of product name in my application page , 
 i want  to just show the name of product in URL for SEO.
and page should be display the content of application page .

wp is my root folder and application is my page

Please Tell me Any solution htaccess or any plugin

How to remove ? from the URL using Htacccess(Wordpress)

I use following htaccess code. But it is not working for my condition .otherwise all  pages are working well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're question is, and you said you are using the following code but I don't see anything in your question.

Comment: It could be that the Apache2 URL Rewriting is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your Permalinks structure.

Go to `Settings > Permalinks > Check the box 'Post Name', i.e. /%postname%/`
[image]

If your .`htaccess` file is not writeable, go to the root of your WordPress installation and add what it tells you to add (The below):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you set your Permalink structure?